# Cursor jumps to end of line after removing node and pressing Enter (Firefox contenteditable)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable

I have this code that removes a node from a `contenteditable` element, but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after removing the node, the cursor jumps to the end of line instead of breaking to a new line. Any way I can fix this? (It works as intended in chrome but not in firefox).

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const target = document.getElementById('target');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const range = document.createRange();

  range.selectNode(target);
  range.deleteContents();
          
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
    Click <span id="target">Button</span> then hit enter
</div>
<button id="button">go</button>
```

### Edit:

It appears that wrapping the contents of the contenteditable within a `div` or `p` tag fixes the issue, but then another issue arises because if the users keeps pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+a backsapace</kbd>...etc the wrapping tag can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this, unfortunately it's very hacky...I really hate contenteditable :( Hope this helps anyone who struggles with this.

The trick is to wrap the contenteditable's content within a `div` or `p` tag, unfortunately this alone isn't enough, because the user might easily remove that tag when he deletes all content and continues to hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> or even delete everything at once using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd>...etc.

So, we also need to make sure to have our wrapper inserted if it doesn't exist.

### steps:

1. Add a `keyup` handler.
2. Check if our wrapper exists.
3. If it does, all is well.
4. If it doesn't:

   1. Save current caret position somehow (I insert a fake element to keep track of its position)
   2. create our element and wrap current content within it.
   3. Restore caret position (and remove the fake element).

It's too much work for something so simple, I really hope that I'm wrong and that a simpler solution exists.

```js
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');

const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const range = document.createRange();
  const target = document.getElementById('target');

  range.selectNode(target);
  range.deleteContents();

  const sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
});

$('.wrapper').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if ($('.wrapper > p').length == 0) {
    pushCaretMarker();
    const html = '<p>' + $(this).html() + '<br></p>';
    $(this).html(html);
    popCaretMarker();
  }
});

function pushCaretMarker() {
  const range = getRange();
  const $span = $('<span id="caret-marker">|</span>');
  range.insertNode($span.get(0));
  range.collapse();
}

function popCaretMarker() {
  const $span = $('#caret-marker');
  if ($span.length > 0) {
    const range = getRange();
    range.selectNode($span.get(0));

    range.deleteContents();
  }
}

function getRange() {
  return window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 20px;
}

.wrapper>p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper>p:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    Click <span id="target">Button</span> then hit enter
  </p>
</div>
<button id="button">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser does it not work for?
Seems to work on IE 11, FF as well as the stated Chrome.

You could always do a key listener and make it do whatever you want.

```
.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    //13 is enter
    if (key === 13){       
       //Do work here.         
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in firefox, after clicking the button when I hit enter the cursor jumps to the end of line instead of breaking the line.